# How hard is it to lift a car?

Tags: homework-and-exercises, newtonian-mechanics, free-body-diagram, estimation

You have a car and would like to lift one side (so that two of the wheels don't lay on the ground). How hard would that be?

I am talking about a car close to the average dimensions: 1200kg, 4m20(length) x 1m80(width) x 1m50(height).

Ideally I would like to know how heavy would be a dumbbell to be as hard to lift.

Comment: Are you talking about lifting it up with your hands or using tools? If you use something like a hydraulic press, then it's fairly easy.

Comment: @FeelMyBlackHole I am asking for a numerical value, something like "as easy as lifting a 300kg dumbbell". I think it should be the same wether you use a hydraulic press or your bare hands, but if I am mistaking please explain.

Comment: A hydraulic press greatly reduces the amount of force you need to apply. The force that is applied to the object by the hydraulic press is much greater than the force you apply.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How much force is required to lift the back of a 2,480 lb car in the air from the bumper?](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/52701/)

Comment: @JohnRennie that's close, but there is a difference in that the other question is about lifting the car from the front (or the back), where mine is about lifting it from the side. The answer is useful though, even if it doesn't directly answer my question.